# I'm trying to copy data from one excel to anther excel using VBN

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy data from one excel to another excel and there is no specific range to define. number of row is dynamic.

using Below code,I can copying the data, but i have run time error 
Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method

```
Sub Copy_Method()
Workbooks("INVCHK.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy Range( "A1")
Workbooks("Reports.xlsm").Worksheets("Data").Range ("A1")
End Sub
```

Comment: Please read the documentation of the [Range.Copy method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy) to see how you define a proper destination. It should be one line like the following: `Workbooks("INVCHK.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Reports.xlsm").Worksheets("Data").Range("A1")` *(<-- all this in one line)*.

Comment: Workbooks("INVCHK.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy_
Workbooks("Reports.xlsm").Worksheets("Data").Range ("A1")............this worked

Comment: while copying the data I need to change the format of the row, from text to number. What is the syntax to do this